# How do I go about creating an array to store multiple different malloc pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'd like to create an array of different malloc pointers. At the moment I am realloc-ing whenever a new chunk of data is added. The mallocs are of structs. The original malloc looks like this:

```
trilist = (triangle *) malloc(1*sizeof(triangle));
```

And then when a function is called, and new information is added, a realloc is used within the function to allow more space.

```
tmp = (triangle *) realloc(trilist, (storage_needed+totaltri)*sizeof(triangle));
trilist = tmp;
```

However, I really want to be able to have an independent malloc each time a function is called and therefore I think an array of pointers may be the best way to do this however I have no idea how to go about implementing that. If someone could show me that'd be very helpful...! And perhaps info on how to free all of that? I'm also unsure about how to initialize the array of pointers when it may have only 1 pointer in it or perhaps 100! I can free the single malloc at the moment via:

```
for(i=0;i<totaltri;i++)
{
    triptr=&(trilist[i]);
    free(triptr->corner);
}

free(trilist);
```

But I also don't know how I would free an array of these. These are my initializers:

```
typedef struct point
{
    double x, y, z;

} point;

typedef struct vector
{
    double x, y, z;

} vector;

typedef struct triangle
{
    point *corner;
    double normvec[3];
    int chopped;

} triangle;

triangle *trilist;
triangle *triptr;
triangle *tmp;
point *pt1ptr;
point *pt2ptr;
point *pt3ptr;
```

Let me know if you need any additional info...!
Thank you.

Comment: `trilist = malloc(1*sizeof *trilist);` is good enough (even better)

Comment: @wildplasser Basically, each time a realloc is used, this is because a new shape (made out of triangles whose coordinates are stored) is added. Instead of this, I wish to have a mall of for each shape so that I may edit each shape and have it’s triangles differentiated from the huge list of them all.